# Windows installation via bootcamp on a MBA mid-2013 without USB or DVD

Tags: bootcamp, macos, usb, windows

I need to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Air Mid-2013 (MacBookAir6,1) via bootcamp, for various reasons I cannot use USB, as far as I know since El Capitan it's possible to install Windows without using a USB or DiskDrive, however only on some newer 2015 models.

[image: So sad]
As you can see OSX tells me to insert the installer disk, I also tried to mount the ISO (no luck even there). Can I spoof my model id to look like a 2015mba? As far as I know no hardware is pulling back this "no-usb" procedure that is available on newer macbooks so it should work even on older MACs.

Answer (score -1):

In order to install Windows via Boot Camp on Mac follow these steps:

Download the Windows iso:

https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO

Open Boot Camp and select the first option.

Open the downloaded iso.

You have to select the size of the partition, after that it should automatically install the drivers and reboot on the Windows installation.

Comment: **without USB or DVD**